# CURL with proxy isn't working

Tags: 20.04, proxy, squid

I have Squid proxy installed on Ubuntu 20.4 LTS.
The squid is listening on port 8118.

When I'm testing it with `curl -x localhost:8118  https://api.ipify.org/?format=json`
It's getting stuck.

When I'm using the Proxy IP it's working outside of the Linux machine.

```
curl -x PROXY_IP:8118
```

What can be the cause of this issue?

Comment: It's not working for me when adding it manually, so why do you think it will work this way?

Comment: Yes, tried it just now, and it's not working.

Comment: I've edited the question, more details added.

Answer (score 1):

Adding rule:

```
sudo iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
```

Solved my issue.